# Responsive transformation of absolute positionned elements in css

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have absolute div blocks placed on certains spots of an image.
Since i want my image responsive, i would like to have the absolute blocks being responsive too. That's where i'm stuck : i could manually resize and translate with css scale and translate proporties, but it's not responsive :

```css
*{margin: 0;padding: 0}
.relat{position: relative;}
.abs {position:absolute;}
.cube1 {background-color: red;border: 1px solid black}
.cube2 {background-color: blue;border: 1px solid black;}
.cube3 {background-color: purple;border: 1px solid black;}
.cube1O {background-color:red;}
.cube2O {background-color: blue;}
.cube3O {background-color: purple;}
.transform{transform-origin: top left;}
.modify{transform: scale(0.5);}
.modify2{transform: scale(0.5) translate(-100%, 0);}
.modify3{transform: scale(0.5) translate(0, -100%);}
```

```html
<div class="relat">
    <div class="abs cube1O" style="top:0px;left:0px;width:200px;height:200px"></div>
    <div class="abs cube2O" style="top:0px;left:200px;width:200px;height:200px"></div>
    <div class="abs cube3O" style="top:200px;left:400px;width:200px;height:200px"></div>
    <div class="abs cube1 transform modify" style="top:0px;left:0px;width:200px;height:200px"></div>
    <div class="abs cube2 transform modify2" style="top:0px;left:200px;width:200px;height:200px"></div>
    <div class="abs cube3 transform modify3" style="top:200px;left:200px;width:200px;height:200px"></div>
</div>
```

The 3 big cubes represent the position on the 100% size image, the 3 smaller (50% here) represent the position on the 50% size image. (but since it's responsive, the transformation could be any percentage).
I can't see by the look of the transform for these 3 blocks (but in reality ther are many more) if there is a unique css transformation to be applied to the cubes.

i'm using

`transform-origin: top left;`

to have the pivot point on the top left corner.
Does it matter or not ?

The problem is with the

`transform: scale(scaleXY) translate(transX, transY);`
i can"t think of a unique set of transfomation for each block.

I would prefer not to have javascript involved.
Is there a way to "simply" perform this task ?
Thank you.

---

EDIT : also, i put the top, left, width and height value in the inline style because in my code, i get them from a database : i can't put them in the css file.

---

EDIT 2 : 
Looking to some post relative to this problem, i've seen that maybe i could fix my problem using percentage for top, left, width, height properties instead of fixed pixel values. i'll look into that.

if NO pure css solution is possible, i would also be interested in a javascript solution.

Comment: What's the issue with using percentage based values? You can also use CSS media queries to apply different css rules to elements for different screen types

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In this "simple" example i have 3 div that i want to scale, keeping their relative position. The problem is i cant apply the SAME transformation to each one. Since i want it to be responsive, i would like to know if there's a unique formula (a transformation matrix of some sorts) that allows me to resize without loosing the relation (block B on the right of block A, block C on bottom right of B). The code i gave as an example is just a "snapshot". I would like to keep the same position if the scale was, say, 30%. It's not a question of screen size here.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to know your exact issue. The problem you are presenting may be due to your approach to your original issue. If you can provide better details about that, may be we can be of help. 

Regarding the responsive css media queries, have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Css can be added dynamically in css classes as well e.g 
<style> 
 .className {
    height: <?php echo $height ?>
}
</style>

Comment: @Meta Pakistani : sorry if the presentation of my problem is not clear enough. I thought the title of my question in itself was self explanatory. i'll try again : can i have a common `scale(xy) translate(x, y)` for every block i could put with an absolute position, that would allow a responsive resizing of the container ? something like https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/

Comment: Thank you so much @Overdose for your suggestion its works the same as I want, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `overflow:hidden;` to the overlay class, is that what you want?